# Default permission says no access For realm created by admin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, realm, realm-object-server

my Realm Object Server is in aws ec2 and whenever I create any realm through admin credentials(synced) and check the ros through IP the default permissions says no access

```
final SyncCredentials syncCredentials = 
SyncCredentials.usernamePassword("username","password",false);
SyncUser.loginAsync(syncCredentials, authUrl, new SyncUser.Callback() 
{
 @Override
public void onSuccess(final SyncUser user) {
SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, 
serverURL)
.schemaVersion(1)/*schemaVersion(1).name("_auth")*/
.build();
realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that by default non-admin users will not be able to read or write to this Realm. If you want to grant permissions to everyone (i.e. wildcard permissions), you can do it with any of the supported SDKs. For example, if you used Swift, you could do:

```
let permission = SyncPermission(realmPath: realmPath,
                                identity: "*",
                                accessLevel: .write)
user.apply(permission) { error in
    // permission applied or an error occurred
}
```

Comment: For me even admin user is having no access for the realm , even though against the user  #of realms is displayed correctly. I ve attached the screenshot of my realm object server and the code I used for loging in as synced user

Comment: The default permissions represent the permissions that everyone gets *unless* they have more specific permissions applied. The owner of the realm has full permissions but that is not reflected in the UI because then it would become super cluttered. If you want to check a specific user's permissions, you can use the Permission Manager: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#access-control. On an unrelated note, it looks like you're using ROS 1 - probably it would be a good idea to upgrade to ROS 2.x before you go into production.

Comment: Thanks it works fine now :) i uninstalled version .0 and installed ROS 2 x working fine now